# Query custom fields with three dates - start and end does not work

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, custom-field, mysql, meta-query

I have tried to make a reservation system for a book a table in restaurant.
But, I have a problem when I try to see/ make new reservations in an specific day - in showing me which table are free at selected interval.

> for eg. I have in total in restaurant `2 tables (A and B)`
> Also I have already booked for day 2023-08-31 those 2 tables (A from 16.00 until 22.00 and B from 15.00 until 23.00)
> Now, I want to be able to book table A or B from same day in other interval (for e.g.A from 08.00 to 15.30) but the problem it is the code show me the table it is already booked even I choose (same day, but another time interval), I guess it is a problem with my `meta_query`

have 3 custom fields  (`for day - _reservation_date_day, start - _reservation_date_hour, end - _reservation_date_hour_end)

```
enter code here
$args = array(  
            'post_type' => 'reservation',//a CPT
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1, 
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'meta_key' => '_reservation_date_hour',
                    'value' => $GMT_checkHour,//the value it is grab using ajax form
                    'compare' => '>=',
                    'type' => 'DATETIME',
                ),
                array(
                    'meta_key' => '_reservation_date_hour_end',
                    'value' => $GMT_checkHourEnd,//the value it is grab using ajax
                    'compare' => '<=',
                    'type' => 'DATETIME',
                ),
                array(
                    'meta_key' => '_reservation_date_day',
                    'value' => $checkDay,//the value it is grab using ajax
                    'compare' => '=',
                ),
            )
        );
```

The problem it is is showing me I don't have any reservation in same day and same interval. Also I tried to make another relation between those to have `AND` only for day and `OR` for start and end interval, in that case - the code showing me all the reservations I have in the select day but this means I will duplicated my reservations....

Answer (score 0):

There is one issue I see in your code. Within 'meta_query' you cannot use 'meta_key', but it should be 'key'. For example:

```
array(
    'key' => '_reservation_date_hour',
    'value' => $GMT_checkHour,//the value it is grab using ajax form
    'compare' => '>=',
    'type' => 'DATETIME',
)
```

So with your previous code all 'meta_key' lines were ignored. To identify such problems, I also suggest using this code:

```
$query = new WP_Query($args);
var_dump($query->request);
exit;
```

to check what WordPress makes from your arguments. This will show you the actual SQL query, which can often help to see what's missing or what would you want to change.

Comment: `SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_reservation_date_day' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS DATE) = '2023-08-31' ) AND ( ( mt1.meta_key = '_reservation_date_hour' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS TIME) >= '2023-08-31 01:00:00' ) OR ( mt1.meta_key = '_reservation_date_hour_end' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS TIME) <= '2023-08-31 02:00:00' ) ) ) AND GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date ASC`

Comment: That it is what it is showing me... but it is still does not work, I changed `meta_key` to `key`